# Niceedit data vallidation PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nicedit

I use Nicedit as a nice tekst editor so that i can use Bold and italic in a text field of mij form. I want to store this tekst in my database, but Nicedit puts al the HTML tags for bold, italic and other in the text. Is there something like a preg_match that validates the text so that i can put it safe in my database.
I don't know if there is an newer sollution in eg. Jquery that does the same and is easier to vallidate, if so what is the best in use?

Answer (score 1):

niceditor output normal text with bold and italic without HTML tags. i can sugest you:

1- download the full script of niceditor (choose all options)

2- look if you dont escape the text variable in your php .